# PROGUARD: with keepInnerClass flag does it lose information on whether its static or not

Tags: java, static, proguard, inner-classes

The `-keepInnerClass` flag does preserve the inner classes.
But does it any how loses information that whether the inner class is static or not.
This is because my original code showed warnings that the Inner Class should be static but after obfuscation it does not do so. Do I have to add any more flags.

Answer (score 1):

You should try updating to a recent version of ProGuard. At this time of writing, we're at version 4.10.

The correct option is actually `-keepattributes InnerClasses`.

You can check if the static flag is set for the inner class by inspecting the output of the `-dump` option (with an optional file name), e.g.

```
.....
Class file attributes (count = 1):
  - Inner classes attribute (count = 1)
    - InnerClassesInfo:
      Access flags:  0xa = private static 
      - Class [test0023/Test$a]
      - Class [test0023/Test]
      - Utf8 [a]
.....
```